# Magento 2: Translate knockout template html text with variables

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

Currently i have a knockout template for minicart like this:

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <div class="items-total">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'There is' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'There are' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->   
        <span class="count"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>        
<!-- /ko -->
```

The text will generate a text like this:

**There is 1 item** or **There are 3 items** the number is the variable i get from `getCartParam('summary_count')` , the problem arise when i need to translate it, for example into this:

```
Hanya ada 1 barang
Terdapat 2 barang
Terdapat 5 barang
```

Using php or phtml file i can easily translate like this:

```
__('There is %1 item in the cart',$item->getQty())
```

Answer (score 1):

The wording is split up, so you need multiple translations excluding the summary count:

- `There is`
- `There are`
- `item`
- `items`

An alternative is to create the string in a JS file and then you can translate it with a variable:

```
$.mage.__('Hello %1').replace('%1', yourVariable);
```

Taken from the [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html#add_strings_js)

Comment: can i use that code in knockout html template ?

Comment: You can create the variable/property in Javascript and then use it in HTML templates with something like this `data-bind="text: yourVariable"`

Answer (score 0):

add your translation in your csv file like this,

- "'There is %1 item in the cart',%2","'There is %1 item in the cart',%2"
- after run the below commands
- bin/magento s:up
- bin/magento s:s:d -f
- bin/magento c:f

Comment: How does that work when the translations do not include variables? For example `<!-- ko i18n: 'There is' --><!-- /ko -->` - The only text there is "There is", there is no variable.